# Django ImportError: PIL in Apache2

Tags: django, apache, python-imaging-library, importerror

I have a trouble to running Django with Apache2. It makes a error when meet a code with **"import PIL"** or **"import Image"**.

In error.log

```
[Mon Apr 02 14:54:35.553626 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 4806] [remote 127.0.0.1:13590]     from PIL import Image
[Mon Apr 02 14:54:35.553634 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 4806] [remote 127.0.0.1:13590] ImportError: No module named 'PIL'
```

But the interest thing is when i command "runserver" with Django, It works very clearly. Could you give me any solution about this problem?

It is setting of  apache2.conf

```
WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-home=/var/www/mysite/virtualenv python-path=/var/www/mysite
WSGIProcessGroup mysite
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py process-group=mysite
```

Thanks.

Comment: you need to `pip install pillow` for the python that apache is using.